# Explain code functionality

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

What is this coding doing...please explain command by command...the expression eqn is a set of nonlinear equations and a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 are the variables of these nonlinear equation..

```
eqn = {(4 Vdc1)/π] (Cos[a1 Degree] - Cos[a2 Degree] + Cos[a3 Degree]) - v1 == 0,
   (4 Vdc1)/(3π) (Cos[3 a1 Degree] - Cos[3 a2 Degree] + Cos[3 a3 Degree]) == 0,
   (4 Vdc1)/(5π]) (Cos[5 a1 Degree] - Cos[5 a2 Degree] + Cos[5 a3 Degree]) == 0
  };

 NMinimize[Norm[Map[First, eqn]], {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}];
```

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: this code is correct and it executes fine...but i dont know how to understand it ....i hv already checked with the mathematica help files...

Comment: You did not answer my question. **Where** (book, paper, answer on this site, etc.) did you see this code?

Comment: this code i got from a thesis (hardcopy) not available on this site.

Comment: which command in which order? what if command "first" doing, what is map doing, and norm , and nminimize doing?

Comment: Did you try doing e.g. `Map[First, eqn]` by itself to see what it does?  Then you can take `Norm` of that, and see what that gives you.  Also see the documentation for e.g. [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html).

Comment: `Map[First,eqn]` takes the first element of each element of `eqn`. `Norm[...]` is the square root of the sum of the squares of the result. `NMinimize[...]` looks for the minimum of this new result when a1, a2, a3, a4 and a5 vary.

Comment: dear All ...i have modified my question to make more clear.

Comment: A simpler, one-equation example is that solving `x - 2 == 0` is equivalent to finding the minimum of `Sqrt[(x - 2)^2]` (which is the norm of one expression).

Answer (score 3):

When we apply `First` to a single equation, it returns the left hand side of the equation.  To get the LHS of each equation in a list, we use `Map[First,●]`.  `Norm` returns the square root of the sum of the squares of a list.  In this case, `Norm` returns the square root of the sum of the squares of the LHS of the equations.  `NMinimize` solves for the values of `a1, a2, a3 ...` that minimize the norm of a vector whose components are the LHSs of equations.

The equations are all of the form LHS=0.  Any set of values for $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots\}$ that satisfy the equations also minimizes the norm.  If `NMinimize` finds a minimum that is very close to zero, one might surmise that the set of $a_i$'s is very close to a solution of the set of equations.  Basically, the code is an attempt to find an approximate solution to the equations.